# guidelines for a new app

Tags: iphone

i want develop a game in which i want to use rolling dice.

plz guide in a proper direction to get going with rolling dices..

How to have a animation on dices.like revolving, providing shake on dice and revolving dice in  360 degree.

regards
shishir

Comment: I want this. Can you do it for me?

Comment: Perhaps you should play around making small test projects that do verious aspects that you may want in you rolling dice game. Accelerometer usage to detect shakes, game logic, basic graphics work. If you don't have a specific question that usually means you don't know enough general background to be attempting such a project without doing hands on learning/testing first.

Comment: @jamone,

sorry my question was not clear.
FYI, i have already work on shake,accelerometer and other graphics functions.

I just need to know,about dice.

how can i use dice animation.
dice is having 6  faces...and revolving 6 faces at a instance is quite a task. so m y intenstion of the question was. how to        have different 3d animation on dices.


thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read a little about accelerometer data and how to interact with objects on the screen, from that.

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html